# Sum results of two sql queries from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have come up with these two queries to find the sum of a field on a single table based on specific where clauses:

```
Select Sum(dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT]) as Total1  
from dbo.Charges 
where (dbo.Charges.[TRAN ID] IN (100, 20, 50, 52, 55, 60, 600))   

Select Sum(dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT]) as Total2  
from dbo.Charges 
where dbo.Charges.[TRAN ID] = 200
```

I'm having trouble figuring out a way to sum the results of both queries together to get a Grand Total.  Any suggestions as to how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `[TRAN ID]` `200` to `IN` clause :

```
SELECT SUM(dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT]) AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM dbo.Charges 
WHERE dbo.Charges.[TRAN ID] IN (100, 20, 50, 52, 55, 60, 600, 200);
```

To get all sums:

```
SELECT
   SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT] <> 200 THEN dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT] END) AS Total1,
   SUM(CASE WHEN dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT] = 200 THEN dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT] END) AS Total2,
   SUM(dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT]) AS GRAND_TOTAL
FROM dbo.Charges 
WHERE dbo.Charges.[TRAN ID] IN (100, 20, 50, 52, 55, 60, 600, 200);
```

Comment: That was simple enough wasnt it I was over complicating. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the rows producing these sums are mutually exclusive, you could just combine the `[TRAN ID]`s in their `where` clauses:

```
SELECT SUM(dbo.Charges.[TRANS AMT]) as GrandTotal
FROM   dbo.Charges
WHERE  dbo.Charges.[TRAN ID] IN (100, 20, 50, 52, 55, 60, 600, 200)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!